# Php Fall on particular Quarter

Tags: php, date

I'm sorry i'm currently having a problem on this section. My Date format is Y-m-d

```
$date1 = '2016-03-1';
$date2 = '2016-07-1';
$date3 = '2016-10-1';
$date4 = '2016-12-1';
```

if today is 2016-8-12 it should fall at $date3 since it the next period.
i tried using the if conditions but it only falls at first condition. Can you enlighten me on this?

My code is somewhat like this

```
$today = date("2016-07-29");
if(strtotime($date1) < strtotime($today)){
        $next_accrual_date = $date1;
        $date_condition = 'condition 1';
    }else
    if(strtotime($date2) <   strtotime($today)){
        $next_accrual_date = $date2;
        $date_condition = 'condition 2';
    }else
    if(strtotime($date3) <  strtotime($today)){
        $next_accrual_date = $date3;
        $date_condition = 'condition 3';
    }else
    if(strtotime($date4) <  strtotime($today)){
        $next_accrual_date = $date4;
        $date_condition = 'condition 4';
    }
echo $next_accrual_date." falls to ".$date_condition;
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: So you basically want to choose one of the 4 dates, which is the closest to the current day? How does your current if condition looks like?

Comment: share your complete code

Comment: i have updated my code my apologies

Comment: why do you using strtotime twice ?

Comment: i have updated the code sorry

Comment: 2016-03-1 means 1st of March 2016 or 3rd of January 2016?

Comment: the format is Y-m-d my bad

Comment: Change all of your "<" to ">" and try it again ;-)

Comment: @RafalKozlowski the Format is  ISO 8601 and this should be like this with strtotime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is

```
<?php
$dates = array();
$dates[] = '2016-03-1';
$dates[] = '2016-07-1';
$dates[] = '2016-10-1';
$dates[] = '2016-12-1';

usort($dates, "cmp");

function cmp($a, $b){ 
    return strcmp($a, $b); 
}

foreach($dates as $date){
  if($date > "2016-08-12"){
    echo $date;
    break;
  } 
}

//print_r($dates);

?>
```

Live demo : https://eval.in/621460

This will give output :

```
 2016-10-1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $today = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));

    $currentYear = date('Y');
    $dates = ['q1' => strtotime($currentYear.'-03-1'), 
                'q2' => strtotime($currentYear.'-07-1'), 
                'q3' => strtotime($currentYear.'-10-1'), 
                'q4' => strtotime($currentYear.'-12-1')];

    foreach ($dates as $qName => $qDate) {
        if ($qDate > $today) {
            return "$qDate falls to $qName";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Change your comparison from < to >:

```
$today = date("2016-07-29");
if(strtotime($date1) > strtotime($today)){
    $next_accrual_date = $date1;
    $date_condition = 'condition 1';
}else ...
echo $next_accrual_date." falls to ".$date_condition;
```

And it will work. currently you look if today is bigger than the date of the first quater, and then break the if. But every date after the '2016-03-1' will be true for this condition. That's why you always get condition 1.